# The element <publishData> is unrecognized, or not supported in this context

Tags: azure, msdeploy, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

Am using TFS 2017 on-premise for building our code. I have used msbuild task with the following parameters.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions=none /p:PublishProfile="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Source\PublishSettings\xxx.azurewebsites.net.publishsettings" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0  /p:Configuration=Release
```

[image]

Log:

```
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6823390Z   Publish Pipeline Deploy phase Stage PipelineCopyAllFilesToOneFolderForMsdeploy
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6823390Z Package:
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6823390Z   Invoking Web Deploy to generate the package with the following settings:
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(LocalIisVersion) is 0
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(DestinationIisVersion) is 0
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(UseIis) is True
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(IisUrl) is http://localhost:7372/
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(IncludeIisSettings) is False
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(_DeploymentUseIis) is False
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(DestinationUseIis) is False
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z GetMSDeployInstalledVersionPath:
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(_DefaultMSDeployMaxVersion) is 3
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(_MSDeployVersionsToTry) is 9.0
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   $(MSDeployPath) is C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles:
2017-12-27T07:43:15.6979640Z   Generate source manifest file for Web Deploy package/publish ...
```

I  got the below error.

```
The element <publishData> is unrecognized, or not supported in this context
```

**I tested my publish setting which is downloaded from azure, it works perfectly fine with the visual studio deployment.** My web api project is of .Net 4.6.1 .

Note: Only this project is not building properly, all other project of .Net 4.5.1 builds, perfectly fine in our on-premise tfs agent.

Comment: What's the result if you build, publish it through MSBuild command manually? Could you share a the build log on the OneDrive (build on on-premise tfs agent)?

Comment: What's the detail code of publishsettings file that works fine for build/publish?

Comment: Could you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wpp files in my working project and now used the same wpp files in the new azure function project and it is all working now. What it really does is, it `xmlpeeks` your publishsettings and makes a publish profile on the fly at msbuild runtime. You can find more details on implementations @ http://sedodream.com/2013/06/05/HowToPublishAVSWebProjectWithAPublishSettingsFile.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The publishsettings file is used to generate publish profile file (Right click Project=> Publish=>Import), there isn’t `<publishData>` section in publish profile, it is in publishsettings file.

So, generate publish profile file per to publishsettings file through VS and use it to publish web app.

There is an article about [publish an Azure Web Site from the Command Line](https://greatrexpectations.com/2013/02/02/publish-an-azure-web-site-from-the-command-line/).

Comment: i have updated the answer , it is basically the publish settings that i downloaded from azure

Comment: I have project that builds with only publish profile, i don't want to use visual studio for any process.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (the project that builds with only publish profile)

Comment: is there a way to share my logs in private, i dont want to share it, here in public ?

Comment: You can remove the sensitive information before share the log.

Comment: i got the above log when i changed the msbuild parameter  PublishProfile  to PublishSettingsFile

Comment: i fixed the issue and answered my own question. Hope it is useful for anyone who does not want to open their visual studio every-time, they change their publish profile or add new stage site to their deployment.